# ASP.NET Identity System Changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

There are many changes in the new ASP.NET Identity system from RC1 to RTM release. I can't find any information on that. Can anyone tell me what I have to change or provide me a link?

For example I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'IdentityManager' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the RC1 of ASP.NET Identity, but I can't find it in the current release. A lot has changed (and a lot has been removed and added) during the different releases. The main classes you should have a look at is [UserManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468199%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and [RoleManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468201%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). They are the main entry point for managing users and roles.